# Reduced speed for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, graph

Over the past two days the speed for retrieval of data through the Microsoft Graph API has diminished tremendously. Downloads that used to take above 5 to 10 seconds have now increased to 30 seconds to 1 minute.

If you could please help me out to resolve the issue, it would be of great help. Users are accessing the API mainly from Australia.

Thanks and Regards,
Noel

Comment: i did not understand what you want, can you please update that question?